# How to get the current running Drush command?

Tags: drush

I would like to detect from code the current running drush command.
I have some hooks that will be run when I exec some drush commands and want to detect which command is triggering the hook.

I manage to get the info from input() but I want to know if there is a more appropriate way:

```
  if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    $command = \Drush\Drush::input()->getArguments()
  }
```

I would like to have something similar to this:

```
  if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    $command = \Drush\Drush::...getCurentCommand();
  }
```

Similar to Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() in someway.

Thank you

Comment: This isn’t an answer but check out its hooks. There might be something there: https://www.drush.org/latest/hooks/. Also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more appropriate way would be to use the object data you get as arguments. Most hooks receive $commandData from where you can get the first argument (the command):

```
$input = $commandData->input();
$command_name = $input->getFirstArgument();
```

Similar to the route name of the matched route you could get the full command name of the matched command via the annotations:

```
$full_command_name = $commandData->annotationData()->get('command');
```

If you need to use static code then get the command name as the first argument like in the question and convert it to the full command name:

```
$command_name = \Drush\Drush::input()->getFirstArgument();
$full_command_name = \Drush\Drush::getApplication()->find($command_name)->getName();
```